# WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__.B is not a constructor

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

I just delete manually some page in my ionic projet and i have some problems now
I deleted the folder of the page and her dependancies in app.module.ts and app.component.ts and all others files that i had "import { PageNamePage } from '../pages/pagename/pagename';"

I use google chrome as browser, 
ionic framework: 3.9.2, 
Angular core: 5.2.9
Node: 6.11.2

And the error is that " WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__.B is not a constructor " in the browser

Just yesterday, all was fine and today i have this problem
Also, i don't know how to delete automatically a page in ionic 3 using visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

There is no command to delete a page in ionic CLI, you need to go over that manually.

If there are no dependencies, then  you gotta restart the ionic server and/or restart the browser too.

Answer (score 0):

i see in  [ionic framework forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com)  that i must get latest versions of common and core modules and plugin
So i do it
(
$ cordova plugin update
$ npm update -f
)
and IT WORK NOW
Thanks you and sorry for my level in english

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by unregistering the service worker (SW) for my app. After that, I've reloaded the app and the error was gone. Probably the problem was in the SW caching.

NOTE: You can unregister SW in the Chrome DevTools under the Application tab.